# Python Postgresql function?

Tags: python-3.x, postgresql

I've got a PostgreSQL function that inserts into 1 public table from another. Here are the create tables and function codes:

```
CREATE TABLE IF NOT EXISTS public.a_input

(
    in_text character varying COLLATE pg_catalog."default"
)
TABLESPACE pg_default;

CREATE TABLE IF NOT EXISTS public.tot_input
(
    in_text character varying COLLATE pg_catalog."default"
)
TABLESPACE pg_default;

insert into public.a_input(
select 'a');

insert into public.a_input(
select 'b');

insert into public.a_input(
select 'c');

CREATE FUNCTION public.inputfunct(
    )
    RETURNS void
    LANGUAGE 'plpgsql'
    COST 100
    VOLATILE PARALLEL UNSAFE
AS $BODY$
BEGIN
INSERT INTO public.tot_input (
SELECT
in_text
FROM public.a_input);
END;
$BODY$;
```

So, the table public.a_input has 3 entries ('a','b','c'). And the public.inputfunct will select those 3 rows and insert them into public.tot_input. I've tested this in PostgreSQL and it works like I expected.

Then, I go over to python and I have this code:

```
#####################

hostname='localhost'

user='postgres'

password='MyPassword'

dbname='postgres'

################

import psycopg2
#########
try:


    con=psycopg2.connect( host=hostname, user=username, password=password, dbname=database )
except NameError:


    print('error')


else:
    print('connected')
    cur=con.cursor()
    cur.callproc("public.inputfunct")
    con.commit


con.close()
```

When I run this, the 'connected' message prints, so I know I'm connecting correctly. I don't get an error when this runs. But, When I select from public.tot_input - there are no rows. It's like the function is running, but no rows end up in the tot_input table. Any suggestions?

Comment: Try `con.commit()` instead of `con.commit`?

Comment: That works, I should have known it was something small...Thanks